# Spring Security Ldap, log in only users in specified group

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

Just like in title, I want that only users of spec. Here is my authentication code:

```
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
    .contextSource(contextSource());
}
```

I found that there are functions like `groupSearchFilter` and `groupSearchBase` or `groupRoleAttribute` but I have no idea how to use them

Answer (score 3):

I made some modifications on Megha's solution

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends  GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {              
            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://ip:port/DC=xxxx,DC=yyyy");
            contextSource.setUserDn("user_service_account");
            contextSource.setPassword("password_user_service_account");
            contextSource.setReferral("follow"); 
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

            LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer = auth.ldapAuthentication();

            ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer
                .userSearchBase("OU=Users,OU=Servers")
                .userSearchFilter("(&(cn={0})(memberOf=CN=GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=Servers,DC=xxxx,DC=yyyy))")
                .contextSource(contextSource);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"(sAMAccountName={0})"
```

should be replaced with following

```
"(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=cn=entergroup,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com))"
```

where cn, ou,dc are the specifications of the group in directory

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your group membership is set up. Something like the following might work, replacing your group dn and objectclasses as necessary:

```
groupSearchBase("cn=yourgroup,ou=groups")
groupSearchFilter("(uniqueMember={0})")
```